# Rendering head :ok vs head :no_content. Any good practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-request, http-response

Whenever I take in data and do something like delete a post, etc. I generally return `head :no_content`.

For example:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find_by(external_id: params[:post_id])
  @post.destroy!

  head :no_content
end
```

Is it good practice to use `head :no_content` over `head :ok`? Not too sure when to use either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior in case of a `DELETE` request. So much so that in rails if you generate a resource or scaffold (using `rails generate`), this is what is generated.

All 2xx statuses are "success" statuses. So if you are actually not sending any content, it is best to mention it with a `no_content`

So rest assured that what you are doing is in fact correct and expected.